# How to remove unity build-in loading screen in Facebook instant game?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, loading

I am working Facebook instant game using unity2017.2. I deployed build for Facebook and uploaded it on Facebook. Everything is fine but when instant game start there is unity loading bar appears which take 8,9 seconds even if you have just one scene with one button in your game. So how can i remove that build-in unity loading screen. Please help. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IodM.png

Comment: Facebook Instant Games are running via WebGL. The engine has to load all files and to start. So you need some loading time. You can modify the `UnityLoader.js` to get your own loading screen.

Comment: @dome12b Thanks you so much buddy. Stay Blessed.

Comment: @dome12b bro how can i customize loading screen. I tried alot but i haven't found anything which i can change.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to skip the whole loading screen. As mentioned in the comments you can modify your `UnityLoader.js` - you can find this script in the `Build` folder of your build.

To read the code I recommend [this beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

I just opend my build and found the object `Progress` in line 1849. Perhaps you have a different version and it is at a different line. Search for `Progress`

Here you can see what Unity is doing. In the `Progress.update` they are updating the ProgressBar.

At all it is not easy to read.

The easy way to customize you loading screen is to replace the graphics under `TemplateData` - here you can copy your own pictures. The names have to be the same as the original filenames: (default is light)

- progressLogo.Light.png
- progressFull.Light.png
- progressEmpty.Light.png

I think this could be a solution for you?

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. This helped me alot. Thanks again buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's a little bit frustrating to see a logo for a long time. I've worked on Unity version 2018.31f, and there, it's easily removable if you are using Unity Pro.

To **remove the logo in Unity Pro**, open your Unity *WebGL project, Go to File -> Build Settings -> Player settings*. You'll see settings for WebGL and a Splash Image column in that window, as shown in this picture.

[image]

As you can see in Splash Image settings, show splash screen column is inaccessible for me to tick/untick. The same goes with Show Unity Logo. This is because I'm currently using a free version of Unity. But in the Unity Pro version, you can untick this option and make that Unity Logo screen hidden.

If you are using the Unity free version, ensure a **minimum Logo Duration of 2-sec**, at least in the accessible version of Unity.